# Converting JSON object to usable sqlalchemy filter statements

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

From the flask component I have request that I call:

```
request_json = request.get_json()
```

This is a JSON object containing the following:

```
{'filter1' : '123', 'filter2' : '456', 'filter3' : '789' }
```

Also these filters can vary in size depending on the front end user. It could be just one filter or multiple.

I am wondering how you would convert an object such as this to a query that would be usable? I believe `or_()` and `and_()` is what I need to use to build the filter. Is it possible to do something such as...

```
query.filter_by(and_(*request_json))
```

I am very new to the entire tech stack...any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter_by` takes keyword arguments to perform basic equality filters.  Remove the `and_` and splat the dict directly into `filter_by`.

```
query.filter_by(**request_json)
```

This does no validation on the keys or values, however.  So if someone passed in `'fish': 3` and there was no "fish" column, or passed in `'column4': 'abc'` and column4 is actually an array type, you would get an error.

So it's probably safer and more straightforward to validate and do the filtering manually.

```
query = MyModel.query

if 'column1' in data:
    try:
        value = int(data['column1'])
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass
    else:
        query = query.filter(MyModel.column1 == value)

if 'column2' in data:
    try:
        value = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(data['column2']))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        pass
    else:
        query = query.filter(MyModel.column2 >= value)

# etc.

return query
```